# How to connect a website to a WCF service

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have a simple one page HTML website to get user input and a WCF service that takes user input and return a list of strings depending on the input.

I would really appreaciate any guidance to connect the two together. Can it only be done with httpBinding and JSON serialization? Is JSON the best practice in this case?

If so, how do I make calls to the service? Do I need any server side scripting or is javascript on the client side enough?

If so, how do I capture and output the return of the service?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of times it's too much unnecessary complication of the system when you create a WCF service, define bindings, endpoints, contracts, host the service and distribute the client when you could simply get the things done with [ASP.NET Page Methods + jQuery](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) even getting rid of ScriptManagers.

You can call a Page Method directly from any .html file, you just need to have a single aspx file on the server, users may even don't know about its existence. The method can return your strings in a single string value, separated with any comma-like sign which is processed by JS later on.

You have a great advantage with page methods, 'cause the service is built into the asp.net web application, you're free of heavy, time-consuming mechanical hand-work every time you have to modify the service. My strong recommendation for you is to make use of page methods if you have an asp.net web app and follow KISS principles.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I use [Ajax Enabled Wcf Service](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016203116/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111710-1.aspx), with Json in this case. It works great for me